# How to keep prompting user until they choose to end the program?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a calculator program with a looping switch.

```
    double firstNum, secondNum;
    int operation;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please enter the first number: ");
    firstNum = keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("\n");

    System.out.print("Please enter the second number: ");
    secondNum = keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("\n");

    System.out.println("Press 1 for addition");
    System.out.println("Press 2 for subtraction");
    System.out.println("Press 3 for multiplication");
    System.out.println("Press 4 for division");
    System.out.println("Press 0 to end the program");
    System.out.println("\n");

    System.out.print("Which operation would you like to perform? ");
    operation = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.print("\n");


    switch (operation)
    {
        case 1:
            System.out.println(firstNum + " + " + secondNum + " = " + (firstNum + secondNum));
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println(firstNum + " - " + secondNum + " = " + (firstNum - secondNum));
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println(firstNum + " * " + secondNum + " = " + (firstNum * secondNum));
            break;
        case 4:
            if (secondNum ==0 )
                    {
                        System.out.println("You can't divide by zero.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println(firstNum + " / " + secondNum + " = " + (firstNum / secondNum));

                    }
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("You have pressed 0. The program is now over.");
    }
```

So, I have this. It works fine if the user just wants to calculate one thing. However, I want to make it so that after they get their first answer, they will be prompted again to enter an operation (so the program loops starting at "Which operation would you like to perform?"). I want the loop to continue until they press 0.

How would I go about doing this? I am new to loops.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use a while loop, where you break out of the while loop when ready to exit. Keep in mind that any break inside of your switch statement will apply to the switch and not the while loop so you may need to maintain a separate variable on whether not to break out of the loop.

For example:

```
boolean continue = true;

while(continue) {
    System.out.print("Which operation would you like to perform? ");
    operation = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.print("\n"); 

    switch (operation)
    {
        case 1:
            System.out.println(firstNum + " + " + secondNum + " = " + (firstNum + secondNum));
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println(firstNum + " - " + secondNum + " = " + (firstNum - secondNum));
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println(firstNum + " * " + secondNum + " = " + (firstNum * secondNum));
            break;
        case 4:
            if (secondNum ==0 )
                    {
                        System.out.println("You can't divide by zero.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println(firstNum + " / " + secondNum + " = " + (firstNum / secondNum));

                    }
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("You have pressed 0. The program is now over.");
            continue = false;
            break;
    }
}
```

This sounds like a homework problem, so spend some time understanding while vs for loops, etc and don't just take this answer and run with it.

Comment: Keep in mind you may need to put your while loop at a different level depending on where you intend them to be able to exit or if you intend them to be able to pick different numbers without exiting the program.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is a `do-while` loop as the actions that you want are guaranteed to happen at least once

```
do
{
    System.out.println("What operation would you like to preform?");
    //do math calculating stuff
    System.out.println("Would you like to do another calculation?");
}

while(scannerScan.nextInt != 0);
```

When you write the `do` portion, put everything that you want to execute repeatedly inside the `do` brackets. In this case I put the SOPs and comment in the brackets, so while `nextInt() != 0` the SOPs will continue to print. This a bit easier to read, and negates any mess-ups in your program that could cause another type of loop to fail guaranteeing that your program will run at least once. After that, if it fails, you know exactly where you messed up, right at the end where the `while` condition is located.

EDIT

I checked up on putting a continue in the default case, and it should work for you. What this does is, if a user inputs a value that is not acceptable, the default executes and the will execute the continue statement which will go straight to the `while` condition. So I suggest you restructure your default case as such:

```
do
{
    int x = 0; 

    switch(x)
    {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Math ops.");
            break;
        case 2:
            //wonderful math
            break;
        case 3:
            //wonders of code
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("You entered invalid input. Try again. Enter a non-zero number to continue.");
            continue;
    }
}

while(scannerScan.nextInt() != 0);
```

Comment: The SOP that tells the user that have quit needs to be in one of the lines AFTER the while condition in my example, in fact, just get rid of the SOP in the default case and make it something else, or get rid of it. While it is recommended to always have a default case to handle errors or unexpected input, I think in this case, you will not really need it, of course you could always drop a `continue` in there and move out of the switch back into the loop, although I'm not sure if that would work. I have never used a `continue` in a switch statement.